# When calling a class using BackgroundWorker nothing happens

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

This is my first post on this site so I apologize if I am not following protocol :)

I have created a form in C#.net and trying to use a BackgroundWorker to call a class.

I have a button for calling the class (named listener) using RunWorkerAsync however when debugging I can't see the class being called and it seems that the debugger steps over it. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace McServer
{
    public partial class app : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public app()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listener.UpdateLabel += UpdateLabelFromListener;

            bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //private void startBtn_Click(BackgroundWorker bw, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bgw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                // Start the asynchronous operation.

                if (ipTxt.Text != "" && portTxt.Text != "" && dirTxt.Text != "")
                {

                    listener t = new listener()
                    {
                        ip = ipTxt.Text,
                        portID = portTxt.Text,
                        path = dirTxt.Text
                    };

                    //bw.DoWork(t);
                    bgw.RunWorkerAsync(t);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fill in all fields first");
                }
            }
        }

        private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                bgw.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
               {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    bgw.ReportProgress(i * 10);
                }
            }
        }

        private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");            
        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "Done!";
            }
        }

        void UpdateLabelFromListener(string message)
        {        
            this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                label5.Text = message;
            }));

        }

        private void brwsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dir = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dir.ShowDialog();
            dirTxt.Text = dir.SelectedPath;
            string path = dirTxt.Text;
        }
```

Comment: For me background worker DoWork event called correctly. did you place the break point in bw_DoWork method while debugging. If still its not called the DoWork method, try to rebuild the application or manually go and delete the bin folder.

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with your "t" instance of `listener` in your DoWork() handler (cast `e.Argument` to work with it).  Are you getting the ProgressChanged() events?...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I do get ProgressChanged() events, the UI text updated with progress percentage. However the listener class does not get stepped into during debugging. Also I am not sure how to work with the "t" instance of listener in the DoWork handler. I assumed it's simply called by the RunWorkerSync!!

Comment: – Idle_Mind, Your comment was correct. I simply removed my "t" instance of 'listener' and called listener class from 'DoWork()' and it's working like a charm . If you flag your comment as answer I can flag it as the right answer. Thanks heaps